# How do while(true) loops affect functions?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am attempting to build a inventory management system for an assignment and I am having a hard time understanding how this While(true) loop is not "blocking" the rest of my code in the function.

For the purpose of the assignment, everything is supposed to be displayed in the console.

The problem is in the main(); function. When I run the code, the prompts appear as expected but when entering the inputs, nothing is displayed in the console until I enter "exit" into the prompt which is when the loop is supposed to break.

Thank you for any assistance.

Below is the code for the assignment thus far,

```js
function displayMenu() {
        window.console.log("The Inventory Management App");
        window.console.log("");
        window.console.log("COMMAND MENU");
        window.console.log("view - View all products");
        window.console.log("update - Update Products");
        window.console.log("del - Delete employee");
        window.console.log("exit - Exit the application");
}

function view(chingaderas){ 
    "use strict";
    var i = 1;
    chingaderas.forEach(function (thing) {
        window.console.log(String(i) + ". " + thing);
        i += 1;
    });
    window.console.log("");
}
            
function update(chingaderas) { // need to find out how to update a specific part of 2 dimensional array 
    "use strict";
var sku = window.prompt("Enter the SKU# of the item you would like to update");
var changeMade = false;
for (var i = 0; i < chingaderas.length; i++) { 
    if (sku == chingaderas[i][0]) {
            var currentStock = window.prompt("How many " + chingaderas[i][1] + " are in stock?");
            changeMade = true;
            if (isNaN(currentStock)) {
                    window.alert("Invalid entry");
                    update(chingaderas);
            } else {
                    chingaderas[i][2] = parseInt(currentStock);
                    window.console.log("The new inventory of " + chingaderas[i][1] + "is now " + chingaderas[i][2]);
            }
    } else if (sku == null) {
            break
    }
}
if (changeMade == false & sku != null) {
        window.alert("Sku number not found")
        update(chingaderas);
}
}
var inventory = [
    [2233, "Hat",    12, "$14.99"],
    [3223, "Socks",  36, "$9.99"],
    [4824, "Shirt",  10, "$15.99"],
    [6343, "Jeans",  22, "$39.99"],
    [9382, "Jacket", 5,  "$49.99"],
];

var main = function () {
   window.console.log("say something")
    
    let command; 
    displayMenu();
    while (true) {
            command = window.prompt("What would you like to do? (view, update, exit)");
            if (command == "view") { // if to view inventory
                    view(inventory); 
            } else if (command == "update") { // to run the update function 
                    update(inventory); 
            } else if (command == "exit"){ // to exit the program 
                   break; 
            } 
            else {
                    window.document.write("invalid entry"); 
            }
    
            
    }
    window.console.log("Program has ended"); 
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the browser time to display the new information. Both `prompt` and `while(true)` *block* - they don't allow the current tab to do *anything* until the `prompt` is finished and the loop has completely finished.

You might have `main` call itself recursively after a `setTimeout` so that things have a chance to render:

```
var main = function() {
  window.console.log("say something")
  let command;
  displayMenu();
  command = window.prompt("What would you like to do? (view, update, exit)");
  if (command == "view") { // if to view inventory
    view(inventory);
  } else if (command == "update") { // to run the update function 
    update(inventory);
  } else if (command == "exit") { // to exit the program 
    window.console.log("Program has ended");
    return;
  } else {
    window.document.write("invalid entry");
  }
  setTimeout(main);
}
```

```js
function displayMenu() {
  window.console.log("The Inventory Management App");
  window.console.log("");
  window.console.log("COMMAND MENU");
  window.console.log("view - View all products");
  window.console.log("update - Update Products");
  window.console.log("del - Delete employee");
  window.console.log("exit - Exit the application");
}


function view(chingaderas) {
  "use strict";
  var i = 1;
  chingaderas.forEach(function(thing) {
    window.console.log(String(i) + ". " + thing);
    i += 1;
  });
  window.console.log("");
}


function update(chingaderas) { // need to find out how to update a specific part of 2 dimensional array 
  "use strict";
  var sku = window.prompt("Enter the SKU# of the item you would like to update");
  var changeMade = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < chingaderas.length; i++) {
    if (sku == chingaderas[i][0]) {
      var currentStock = window.prompt("How many " + chingaderas[i][1] + " are in stock?");
      changeMade = true;
      if (isNaN(currentStock)) {
        window.alert("Invalid entry");
        update(chingaderas);
      } else {
        chingaderas[i][2] = parseInt(currentStock);
        window.console.log("The new inventory of " + chingaderas[i][1] + "is now " + chingaderas[i][2]);
      }
    } else if (sku == null) {
      break
    }
  }
  if (changeMade == false & sku != null) {
    window.alert("Sku number not found")
    update(chingaderas);
  }
}

var inventory = [
  [2233, "Hat", 12, "$14.99"],
  [3223, "Socks", 36, "$9.99"],
  [4824, "Shirt", 10, "$15.99"],
  [6343, "Jeans", 22, "$39.99"],
  [9382, "Jacket", 5, "$49.99"],
];


var main = function() {
  window.console.log("say something")
  let command;
  displayMenu();
  command = window.prompt("What would you like to do? (view, update, exit)");
  if (command == "view") { // if to view inventory
    view(inventory);
  } else if (command == "update") { // to run the update function 
    update(inventory);
  } else if (command == "exit") { // to exit the program 
    window.console.log("Program has ended");
    return;
  } else {
    window.document.write("invalid entry");
  }
  setTimeout(main);
}

main();
```

If at all possible, it would be better to avoid `prompt` entirely, since it's pretty user-unfriendly and prevents rendering and interaction with the page - consider creating an input box and a button on the page instead.